# Validate object against a schema before serialization

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, jsonschema

I want to serialize a C# object as JSON into a stream, but to avoid the serialization if the object is not valid according to a schema. How should I proceed with this task using JSON.NET and Json.NET Schema? From what I see there is no method in the JSON.NET library which allows the validation of a C# object against a JSON schema. It seems somewhat weird that there is no direct method to just validate the C# object without encoding it. Do you have any idea why this method is not available?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this? https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm

Comment: You could grab `NullJsonWriter` from [Reference to automatically created objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30650904/3744182) then wrap it in a `JSchemaValidatingWriter` and test-serialize your object as shown in [*Validate JSON with JSchemaValidatingWriter*](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/JsonValidatingWriterAndSerializer.htm).

Comment: @dbc It seems somewhat weird that there is no direct method to just validate the C# object without encoding it. Do you have any idea why this method is not available?

Comment: *It seems somewhat weird that there is no direct method to just validate the C# object without encoding it.* -- possibly because generating values to validate is 90% of the work of encoding it?  (Questions like "Why did company X do Y" are mostly OT for stackoverflow.)

Comment: Well this is a [Vexing Exception](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) so you just have to serialize it then test it.  You can't avoid serializing it.

Comment: @dbc I do not understand what you mean by 'generating values to validate is 90% of the work of encoding it?' The absence of object validation it is suggesting to me that it is good enough to just encode the object to memory using a StringWriter and in the valid case write that into the stream. But I am not really sure about this, because to me the more intuitive (and efficient) solution seems to be to validate the object first, without serializing it, and then serializing it to a stream. Encoding to memory and writing to a stream afterwards seemed somehow wrong to me.

Comment: @bosonix - Again just guessing here, but to "validate the object" Json.NET would need to descend the object hierarchy, generate a contract for each object encountered, fetch values from members, convert the primitive values to JSON format invoking all relevant converters, then compare the serialized primitive values against the primitive values in the JSON schema.  That seems like > 50% of the work of serialization.  Note that http://json-schema.org/ was made to *annotate and validate JSON documents.* so to validate an *object* you're going to need to make the object look like JSON.

Comment: But you could always [file an enhancement request](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) if you want, it's not a crazy thing to ask for, it's just not there yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this API not currently available.  At a guess, this might be because recursively generating the JSON values to validate involves most of the work of serializing the object.  Or it could just be because no one at Newtonsoft [ever designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented and shipped that feature](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/22/why-doesnt-c-implement-top-level-methods/).

If you want, you could [file an enhancement request](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) requesting this API, probably as a part of the [`SchemaExtensions` class](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_SchemaExtensions.htm).

In the meantime, if you do need to test-validate a POCO without generating a complete serialization of it (because e.g. the result would be very large), you could grab `NullJsonWriter` from [*Reference to automatically created objects*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30650904/3744182), wrap it in a `JSchemaValidatingWriter` and test-serialize your object as shown in [*Validate JSON with JSchemaValidatingWriter*](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/JsonValidatingWriterAndSerializer.htm).  `NullJsonWriter` doesn't actually write anything, and so using it eliminates the performance and memory overhead of generating a complete serialization (either as a `string` or as a `JToken`).

First, add the following static method:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static bool TestValidate<T>(T obj, JSchema schema, SchemaValidationEventHandler handler = null, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        using (var writer = new NullJsonWriter())
        using (var validatingWriter = new JSchemaValidatingWriter(writer) { Schema = schema })
        {
            int count = 0;
            if (handler != null)
                validatingWriter.ValidationEventHandler += handler;
            validatingWriter.ValidationEventHandler += (o, a) => count++;
            JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings).Serialize(validatingWriter, obj);
            return count == 0;
        }
    }
}

// Used to enable Json.NET to traverse an object hierarchy without actually writing any data.
class NullJsonWriter : JsonWriter
{
    public NullJsonWriter()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
// Example adapted from 
// https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/JsonValidatingWriterAndSerializer.htm
// by James Newton-King

string schemaJson = @"{
   'description': 'A person',
   'type': 'object',
   'properties': {
     'name': {'type':'string'},
     'hobbies': {
       'type': 'array',
       'maxItems': 3,
       'items': {'type':'string'}
     }
  }
}";         
var schema = JSchema.Parse(schemaJson);

var person = new
{
    Name = "James",
    Hobbies = new [] { ".Net", "Blogging", "Reading", "XBox", "LOLCATS" },
};

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
var isValid = JsonExtensions.TestValidate(person, schema, (o, a) => Console.WriteLine(a.Message), settings);
// Prints Array item count 5 exceeds maximum count of 3. Path 'hobbies'.

Console.WriteLine("isValid = {0}", isValid); 
// Prints isValid = False
```

Watch out for cases by the way.  Json.NET schema is [case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43188628/3744182) so you will need to use an appropriate contract resolver when test-validating.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ggWCwh).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that from the JSON string, you need an object and a schema to compare with first..

```
public void Validate()
{
    //...
    JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse("{'pattern':'lol'}");
    JToken stringToken = JToken.FromObject("pie");
    stringToken.Validate(schema);
```